# How to migrate build with xml-maven-plugin transformation to sbt?

Tags: maven, sbt

Context: I'm trying to convert an existing scala project that's been built using maven to SBT so I can take advantage of the multiple scala version building logic that SBT brings to publish 2.10 and 2.11 artifacts for [this library](https://github.com/dkowis/wadl-tools).

Problem I'm running into is replicating the xml-maven-plugin transformation [configuration](https://gist.github.com/dkowis/531f42262e05f47a071a) (I used a gist, because it didn't paste into here very nicely at all, and it's not small)

Is my solution to re-implement whatever the xml-maven-plugin is doing in scala code in a `Build.scala` (or other file) and use it in `build.sbt` as a task? Is there an existing plugin out there for SBT that can do XSL transformations? Is there a much simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to stick with the maven plugin using [sbt maven plugin](https://github.com/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin). It may or may not mess with your build, but may be worth a try at least.

For pure scala, you have something like [sbt-xslt-plugin](https://github.com/jm2dev/sbt-xslt-plugin). It's very immature and outdated. However, you may be able to quickly modify it to do the tasks you were using xml-maven-plugin for. The amount of scala code that makes up that plugin is about as much xml code you have in your xml-maven-plugin config, so it should be a heavy task.